# How to get full details of a page using cid

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

Currently we are using place details API to get details using place id.
But I want to use google CID to get the details same like as place id

Is there any API to get details using google CID instead of place id.
Please suggest.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances in getting help from the community. And please be advised that seeking recommendations about what API to use is against the question guidelines and would be off topic. we strongly recommend that you spend a reasonable amount of time researching the problem and searching.